# Deploy WebSharper 2.4 sitelet on IIS7.5

Tags: f#, iis-7.5, websharper

I created a websharper sitelet project from Visual Studio 2012, which I called SiteletTest.

I compiled this project.

Then I copied SiteletTest/Web to inetpub/wwwroot.

Then I go to `localhost/SiteletTest`, `localhost/SiteletTest/Home` and `localhost/SiteletTest/home` but in each case I get http 404.

If I go to `localhost/Main.html` then I get a page, so going to this directory seems to work, but websharper doesn't appear to be working.

My web.config is below, and I have no idea what else to do.  I already set the application pool to use .net 4:

```xml
<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <authentication mode="Forms" />
  <pages>
   <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="WebSharper" namespace="IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Web" assembly="IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Web" />
    <add tagPrefix="ws" namespace="Website" assembly="Website" />
   </controls>
  </pages>
  <httpModules>
   <add name="WebSharper.Remoting" type="IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Web.RpcModule, IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Web" />
   <add name="WebSharper.Sitelets" type="IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Sitelets.HttpModule, IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Sitelets" />
  </httpModules>
 </system.web>
 <system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <modules>
   <add name="WebSharper.Remoting" type="IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Web.RpcModule, IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Web" />
   <add name="WebSharper.Sitelets" type="IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Sitelets.HttpModule, IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Sitelets" />
  </modules>
 </system.webServer>
 <runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
   <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
   </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
  <assemblyBinding appliesTo="v4.0.30319" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
   <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
   </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
 </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I am not going to be paying for a license until I get an idea if this may work for my needs, so, **how do I get this to work**?

I don't want to copy the sitelet code, but here are some fragments:

```
   type Action =
        | Home
        | Contact
        | Protected
        | Login of option<Action>
        | Logout
        | Echo of string
```

and another fragment:

```
module Pages =

    /// The home page.
    let HomePage : Content<Action> =
        Skin.WithTemplate "Home" <| fun ctx ->
            [
                H1 [Text "Welcome to our site!"]
                "Let us know how we can contact you" => ctx.Link Action.Contact
             ]
```

Comment: We cannot help you based on the above bits and pieces. Why not send your complete project?

Comment: At this point it could be (a) WebSharper module does not load in your IIS; (b) or the URLs you are trying are not the ones defined by your WebSharer router object. Does the project work in dev server? Is IIS on the same machine as the dev server? What's your router? Is IIS configured to serve the site? At root or in a virtual directory?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you are missing 1 of three things:

1- Your sitelet/router isn't defined... something like this:

```
type Site() =
    interface IWebsite<Action> with
        member x.Sitelet =
            Sitelet.Infer
            <|  function
                | Home -> Pages.HomePage
                ...
        member x.Actions = []
```

This maps each of the action cases to the correct page. There are many ways to define it but the above Sitelet.Infer will simply map the route by name.

2- You did not specify a Website assembly attribute... something like this:

```
[<assembly : Website(typeof<Site>)>]
do ()
```

I think this tells ASP.NET to load the above Sitelet as your site.

3- A third option is to automatically load a client-side JavaScript control from a Default.aspx page in the C# Web Project. If you use the Web Application (ASP.NET) template, you will see an example of that... but with that I do not think you can control the URL Path in a REST-full manner.